# aiohttp ServerDisconnectedError

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp to communicate to devices API, I'm only sending one request at a time for one device and wait for response before sending another,  when using the script to query many devices at once i receive a lot of ServerDisconnectedError, but when run on only one device it works fine without any errors

script used to query conf of multiple devices

```
async def download_conf(devices, *args, **kwargs):
   semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(5) # --> even with Semaphore I still get the error a lot
   async def create_semaphore_task():
       async with semaphore:
         downloader = await query_conf(device=device, *args, **kwargs)
       return downloader
   tasks = dict()
   for device in devices:
      tasks[device['name']] = asyncio.create_task(create_semaphore_task())
   results, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks.values())
```

below is the code to send request to device API first I should create session and login first for each device, when i added try except to catch ServerDisconnectedError and try after it again the query is working

```
async def request(self, method='GET', url='', **kwargs):
    retries = 2
    while retries > 0:
        try:
            self.resp = await self.session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
            break
        except (aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError) as e:
            retries -= 1
            if retries == 0: raise e
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return await self.resp.read()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853195/getting-serverdisconnectederror-exceptions-would-connection-release-help-fix

Comment: see if it helps

Comment: he is talking about handling errors and that is what I'm doing, but my question is why this happens when run against multiple devices and doesn't happen when run against one